# unsupported directive '.stabs'

Tags: gcc, clang

I'm compiling my code with clang while compiling i'm getting below error with satbs

:1:8: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
.stabs "warning",30,0,0,0
       ^
:2:8: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
.stabs "_setlocale",1,0,0,0
       ^

Comment: Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: #define __warn_references(sym,msg)              \
              __asm(".stabs \"" msg "\",30,0,0,0");   \
              __asm(".stabs \"_" #sym "\",1,0,0,0");

Comment: here is the complete code ----  https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/StdLib/Include/sys/cdefs_aout.h